# I can't save Many to Many with through model, using ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I'm stuck trying save many to many relationship through custom model, using ModelMultipleChoiceField. Django shows this error: `Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Project: MARKETING 7>]>": "ProjectEmployee.project" must be a "Project" instance.`

I can't find solution for this.

##### models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=200, unique=True)

class Employee(models.Model):
    project = models.ManyToManyField(Project, through='ProjectEmployee')
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=200, unique=True)
    lastname = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=200, unique=True)

class ProjectEmployee(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
```

##### forms.py

```
class ProjectEmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    project = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        required=True,
        queryset=Project.objects.all(),
    )
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectEmployee
        fields = '__all__'
```

##### views.py

```
def project_employee(request, id):
    employee = get_object_or_404(Employee, id = id)
   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectEmployeeForm(
            request.POST or None,
        )     
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save(commit=False)
            f.employee = employee
            f.save()
            redirect('employe:list')
    else:
        form = ProjectEmployeeForm()
    
    template = 'prject_employee.html'
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, template, context)
```

##### urls.py

```
path('<int:id>/project_employee/', project_employee, name='project_employee'),
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show your `ProjectEmployee` model.

Comment: @evergreen, Edited form show ProjectEmployee model.

Comment: You want a [model formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets-1) for `ProjectEmployee` and then simply `ModelChoiceField` in it for both `project` and `employee`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you are attempting to assign a value of type `<QuerySet [<Project>]>` to a value expecting type `Project`.

Wherever you are setting the value, you seem to be using the results of a query which may or may not return multiple answers.

Maybe instead of using `all()` there is an option to return a single `Project` object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need use ModelMultipleChoiceField for select multiple projects for one employe, there is the problem, with "Select" widget, for one project no problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up a many-to-many relationship such as employees and projects, the database can't actually store one record with multiple employees or multiple projects. It has to use an intermediate table, aka a join table or a through table. The intermediate table stores one relationship at a time (one employee and one project).

So when you set up a `ProjectEmployeeForm`, it expects that you will be selecting one `project`, selecting one `employee` and entering a `date_joined`. The default form field for a `ForeignKey` is a `ModelChoiceField`, which allows you to select one object. If you override it with a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` the widget will handle the input and allow you to select any number of objects, but when you submit the form, as you discovered, it doesn't have any way to save multiple objects in one foreign key field. In order to use the form, you need to use the default `ModelChoiceField` widgets instead and submit the form again for every project-employee pair that you need to enter.

The alternative is to use an `EmployeeForm`. That, of course, will have a `ManyToManyField` for projects. Django expects to use a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` for that and it will know how to save the appropriate values in the intermediate `ProjectEmployee` table behind the scenes. The downside is that the default `EmployeeForm` wouldn't know about the `date_joined` field and you would need extra code to handle that. I personally think using the `ProjectEmployeeForm` as you did is clearer and simpler when you have extra fields in the intermediate table.